# Read the dataset in SQL and determine the value

Tags: sql, dataset, hana, sap-erp

I have the following dataset and would like to display text based on the PIR of the material + plant combination.

**If for a given material and plant combination I have only 1 PIR then a new column is needed that says 'Single' else 'Multiple'.**

I have also applied a ranking to the dataset but don't know how to take it up from this point on.

[image: Sample Dataset]

EDIT: The dataset so far has been done through HANA modeling. SAP tables:

```sql
SELECT "MAPL_MANDT", "MAPL_MATNR", "MAPL_WERKS", "MAPL_MMSTA", "MAPL_BESKZ", "MAPL_MMSTD", 
       "CC_MATERIAL_STATUS", "INFNR", sum("CC_COUNT") AS "CC_COUNT", 
       sum("Rank_Column") AS "Rank_Column" 
FROM "_SOURCE_DETERMINATION_MOCK" 
GROUP BY "MAPL_MANDT", "MAPL_MATNR", "MAPL_WERKS", "MAPL_MMSTA", "MAPL_BESKZ", "MAPL_MMSTD", 
         "CC_MATERIAL_STATUS", "INFNR"
```

Comment: Can you post some code to show what you have tried?

Comment: The dataset so far has been done through HANA modeling. SAP tables     SELECT
  "MAPL_MANDT",
  "MAPL_MATNR",
  "MAPL_WERKS",
  "MAPL_MMSTA",
  "MAPL_BESKZ",
  "MAPL_MMSTD",
  "CC_MATERIAL_STATUS",
  "INFNR",
  sum("CC_COUNT") AS "CC_COUNT",
  sum("Rank_Column") AS "Rank_Column" 
FROM "_SOURCE_DETERMINATION_MOCK" 
GROUP BY "MAPL_MANDT",
  "MAPL_MATNR",
  "MAPL_WERKS",
  "MAPL_MMSTA",
  "MAPL_BESKZ",
  "MAPL_MMSTD",
  "CC_MATERIAL_STATUS",
  "INFNR"

Comment: Anyone can assist on this problem please? I am new to SQL as I come from SAP ABAP background.

Comment: @Raza You may have already addressed this; but I'm new to sap/hana and a long time SQL user  So coming from a opposite side.   Response below.

Answer (score 0):

I would think a standard SQL analytic count() with a case statement would do the trick.

`Case when Count(*) over (partition by MATNR, WERKS) > 1 then 'Multiple' else 'Single' end as Type`

```
SELECT "MAPL_MANDT"
     , "MAPL_MATNR"
     , "MAPL_WERKS"
     , "MAPL_MMSTA"
     , "MAPL_BESKZ"
     , "MAPL_MMSTD"
     , "CC_MATERIAL_STATUS"
     , "INFNR"
     , sum("CC_COUNT") AS "CC_COUNT"
     , sum("Rank_Column") AS "Rank_Column" 
     , CASE WHEN Count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY MATNR, WERKS) > 1 THEN 'Multiple' 
            ELSE 'Single' end as Type
FROM "_SOURCE_DETERMINATION_MOCK" 
GROUP BY "MAPL_MANDT"
       , "MAPL_MATNR"
       , "MAPL_WERKS"
       , "MAPL_MMSTA"
       , "MAPL_BESKZ"
       , "MAPL_MMSTD"
       , "CC_MATERIAL_STATUS"
       , "INFNR"
```

The SQL line I added basically says..  Get a count(*) for each record GROUPED (partitioned) by MATNR, WERKS and assign it to each record.  Then evaluate (`Case when <condition> then else end`) the record's count assigned  and if the result is > 1 it's 'multiple', if it's anything else 'single'.

in SQL `"`'s are generally only needed if spaces are in the column name.  Eliminating them may improve readability. Also they may force the column name match to be case specific.  (they do in I'm sure the Hana Studio environment adds them for you when you drag/drop the columns though.